# MVC4 model life time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a web app with Asp.net mvc4 ... and I am pretty new to the subject.

My model is opening a connection to a database (not an sql db, no EF).

In the controller on `Index()` I create an instance of the model, which is then passed to the view (`return View(model)`) to display data ... all fine.

`Index` is called on every refresh of the page (F5 in IE). This means I create an instance of my model with every refresh. The model contains a call to "`MyDB.CloseConnection()`" in its destructor - but it is never called.

Questions:
What is is the life time of controller and model?
(I expected the destructor to get called once the page is fully displayed).
I read various docs about the page life cycle, but didn't find a specfic hint on when the model or controller get disposed.

Is it generally a good idea to create a new instance of the model in the `Controller.Index()` method, or should I keep a reference in a 'global' (though user specific) 'space'? What would be such a 'space'?

Thanks for any hints, Thilo

(if the anser is "RTFM!" -> what is the recommended M? ;-)